# Why does computer show device mapping table on EFI shell after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a single board computer. I booted from a USB drive with the correct image on there and went through the menus that installed Ubuntu. Once the computer restarted I unplugged the USB drive and got the following menu:

EFI Menu After Ubuntu Installation

[image]

I don't know why it's not booting into Ubuntu itself and if I try to restart the installation process the Ubuntu installer recognizes that there is an existing installation. Based on the limited research I've done online, I think I need to do something to the partitions, although I'm not sure what or why.

I've tried using GRUB by keeping the USB in to do the steps in the [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen), but I can't get very far due to my inability to find the files/folders specified.

Comment: Have you run boot-repair? That's the first thing to try. Search this site for detailed procedure.

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary workaround, try typing these commands at the EFI shell (the `Shell>` prompt in your image):

```
fs0:
cd EFI\ubuntu
shimx64.efi
```

This sequence *should* launch GRUB, which in turn should launch Ubuntu. There are a number of reasons why this might fail, but chances are good that it will work.

Once Ubuntu is booting, run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base a more permanent answer on more than guesswork.

If you can't get Ubuntu to boot using my workaround, you can run Boot Repair from the Ubuntu installer booted into its "try before installing" mode.

Comment: Thanks but I'm beginning to suspect that the hardware I'm using is faulty. I noticed that the motherboard is reset even when Ubuntu isn't installing and so I'm thinking there's either a watchdog that is resetting the system after a specific time or the hardware is just messed up and I need a new board. Either way I'll update you with what I find.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have the same issue(on a Dell Chromebook 13 7310) and your response has finally gotten me into ubuntu, you rock.

only issue is that after reboot it repeats the problem. options to add flags in the "Boot Repair" utility weren't available.

here is the info.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26262059/

After some google searching I found a response that made the solution permanent via copying a file. 
some explanation would be nice on this workaround as it's not very clear to me how it worked.
https://askubuntu.com/a/906821/310848

thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case with ArchLinux first I just had to enter

```
mount fs0
```

Then

```
fs0:
cd EFI\ubuntu
shimx64.efi
```

Solved it.

Thanks!!