# Windows/Linux Dual Boot Error: "Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I am a Windows 11 user and I have been using linux via ubuntu dual boot. The dual boot has been working wonderfully for months, until one day it stopped working for seemingly no reason. When I boot up the computer, I do not get to choose ubuntu/windows thru grub, instead I get the following error message on my boot up screen:

```
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found  
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi:Not Found  
start_image() returned Not Found, falling back to default loader  
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found  
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi:Not Found  
start_image() returned Not Found
```

As of right now, I can access my default windows OS, but I can't access the linux portion of my computer at all. I tried a couple things that other people have been suggesting on other forums. I already went into BIOS and disabled secure boot, and I also made sure that ubuntu is at the top of the boot order. None of this has worked for me. When ubuntu is at the top of the boot order, I can't even access windows either, the computer just shows me a black screen.

I tried running the boot-repair, and I had a problem with this as well. I accessed linux with a usb, and I ran the boot-repair commands on terminal. I chose the "recommended repair" option but the repair system got stuck, showing me a message that says "Applying changes. This may require several minutes..." I left it on but hours but I was not able to complete boot repair, never getting past this message. So basically not even the boot-repair program seems to be functioning properly.

Is there any way to fix this situation? Like I said earlier, I was using windows/linux dual-boot fine for months, I just don't know why this happened, nor how to fix it. Please let me know if you need anymore information from me. Here is the BootInfo summary link that I acquired through the Boot-repair system:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fhzNxsRxgq/

Comment: Your UEFI entry shows shimx64.efi not grubx64.efi. And it looks like you installed grub customizer. That replaces grub's script files with its own proxy files. One opinion of grub customizer. https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/grub-customizer.html Not sure if customizer updated for grub 2.06. Some suggest removing customizer, renaming script's folder /etc/grub.d, so not to have duplicate files & do a total reinstall of grub-efi-amd64 with Boot-Repair's advanced mode to get back to default version of grub.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this error using the solution here:

[Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found (Dual Boot Ubuntu with Windows 10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356544/failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx64-efi-not-found-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows)

The commands I ran were:

```
sudo mount -tvfat /dev/nvme0n1 /mnt  
sudo cp /cdrom/EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/
```

Now everything is working fine, thank goodness.

Answer (score -1):

Restore Dual Boot Menu Using the System Configuration Tool:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open Run.
- Type `msconfig` and click OK to open the *System Configuration* utility.
- Here, open the *Boot* tab.
- Select the OS that is not set as default and click the *Set as default* button.