# Dual boot: Windows/Ubuntu Grub is not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Instead of having the Grub menu appear to make a selection of which OS, I get the message:

```
Failed to open\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not found
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Not found
start_image() returned Not Found, falling back to default
```

The computer then goes into Windows.

I am a newbie, so please be explicit about any solution. Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Please tell me the make of your laptop (HP, Dell, Lenovo, etc.), and then I will be able to answer this question properly.

Comment: hmm... why does the path have "unbuntu" instead of "ubuntu"? Did you make a typo when writing this question, or did you make a typo when attempting some kind of manual configuration?

Comment: is the partition encrypted?

Comment: It is a Dell Inspiron laptop. I don't think Ubuntu is misspelled. No, I don't believe the partition is encrypted. After months of working perfectly, this error just appeared. I wonder if it is the result of an update?.

Comment: if you are a newbie, it may be too difficult, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906776/error-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx64-efi-dual-booting), it's the same problem and a bunch of possible ways to overcome it

Comment: Thank you, Andra. I pretty much understand what they are saying, and I will work my way through it. It is very kind of you to help me out. I am grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I use Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04, but I think it might be the similar solution for you.

1. Create a live USB/disk of Ubuntu
2. If you are using Windows 10/11, search for `change advanced startup options`
3. `Advanced Start Up` -> `Restart Now`
4. Select `Use a Device`
5. Select your USB that has Live Ubuntu on it
6. Select Ubuntu and Select `Try Ubuntu`
7. Connect Internet(Wifi)
8. Open terminal and type:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update

   sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
9. Select `Recommended repair`

As an alternative solution that I didn't apply:

- start Command Prompt on Windows and type:

  bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
- **Source** : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair