# Future Proof This Problem?: Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found:

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

This question intends to determine best how to avoid this problem in the future.

After Windows performed an update on 2/26/24 (after several months of not using Windows). Booting presented this error and launched into Windows 11:

*Failed to load image: Not Found*

*start-image() returned Not Foundk falling back to default loader*

*Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grub64.efi - Not Found*

*Failed to load image: Not Found*

*Start_image () returned Not Found*

After many false starts, I found a solution that worked for me.
[Dual boot: Windows/Ubuntu Grub is not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398417/dual-boot-windows-ubuntu-grub-is-not-found)

This I the result of Ubuntu boot repair if it's helpful:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xQH9V4Z7ct/

As I’m very inexperienced with much of this what I can do to prevent Windows from messing up my grub file in the future?
In my ‘bios’ should I disable:  Enable UEFI Capsule Firmware Updater (default is on)?  It seems this might prevent the issue I had but it also seems like potential future trouble.

Running a Dell xps 9710 with a dual boot partitioned hard drive.  Using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and Win 11.

Regards,
Evan

Comment: Why are you getting an error on grubx64.efi? Your UEFI shows it using shimx64.efi which is for either UEFI Secure boot on or off. Not sure if grub error or Boot-Repair's choot on efivars. I gather efivars at some time may have been in /lib/modules/.. kernel version but on my system it is not there. It is mounted at: efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars.  One user posted that this resolved that issue include in chroot `mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars` Windows & UEFI updates often reset boot order. You just have to redo and can use efibootmgr from live installer.