# Grub menu not showing OS names after installing 3rd os

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So i had windows and Ubuntu on my HDD, initially.
Recently i got SSD alongside HDD and tried to install a new Ubuntu on SSD. The process went smoothly until the very end, but when i booted the grub menu was showing up.
I tried to repair by

1. using bcdedit

'''bcdedit /set {bootmgr} \EFI\boot\shimx64.efi'''

It didn't work

2. Got live Ubuntu on pendrive, got into  the os. Tried updating grub.

Unfortunately, This also didn't work.

Comment: What exactly does grub show? Anything? Also, can you edit your question to include the output of `lsblk`? Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with grub menu showing up? That's what should happen in a multiboot szenario.

Comment: @mook765 its not wrong i understand that. But the installed software should be on ssd, and on booting, 3  os (one ubuntu on ssd, one on hdd, one windows os) should show up.

Comment: @cocomac thanks for your response. I happened to solve it by using  siva surya's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1134107/1370321.

Answer (score 0):

siva surya's answer solved the issue. [https://askubuntu.com/a/1134107/1370321[1]](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134107/1370321%5B1%5D)

However, additionaly, i had to do some other stuff.
since we've installed ubuntu on SSD, the grub is now confused between the previous installed ubuntu on HDD, and new installed ubuntu on SSD. (we have to change BIOS setting (later)).

Follow the steps of using a bootabe USB to get into ubuntu. use boot-repair. Till this part its same.

Next, while boot-repair is ongoing, do use the advanced options:
opt for boot from HDD, instead of boot from SSD.